# Using cookies to check if anonymous user voted

Tags: javascript, cookies, flask

I'm working on a webapp that uses Flask as the backend server. There are posts that I'm storing in an SQLAlchemy database, and I want the users to be able to upvote/downvote them without having to log in. I wrote a JavaScript function for upvoting/downvoting that increments the current vote count and then updates the count in the database using Ajax. I want to make sure that the same user doesn't vote on the same post twice; it doesn't have to be robust. I read that cookies could be used for that purpose, or a combination of cookies and IP. I'm having a hard time understanding how to get started: do I assign a cookie to a user in JS or in Flask? How do I check whether the user already voted? I'd appreaciate if someone could show me a simple example or direct me to a good resource. Thanks a lot.

Here's my Javascript part for upvoting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#{{ upbtnID }}').click(
            function() {
                var postID = "{{ answer.id }}";
                var data = {
                    'id': "{{ answer.id }}"
                };
                var score = document.getElementById('{{ scoreID }}');
                var scoreText = score.textContent;
                var scoreToInt = parseInt(scoreText, 10);
                var newScore = ++scoreToInt;
                var scoreToStr = newScore.toString();

                $(this).css('border-bottom-color', '#26EDEB');
                score.textContent = scoreToStr;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/upvote",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {;
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        alert("Awww");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And the corresponding function in Flask:

```
# upvote a post
@app.route('/upvote',  methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upvote():
    if request.method =="POST":
        thePostID = int(request.json["id"])
        thePost = Answer.query.get(thePostID)
        thePost.score += 1
        db.session.commit()
        data = thePost.score
        return ('', 204)
```

Comment: As a side note, it would be better if you updated the SQL using a transaction or a different safety measure - otherwise, if two users voted at the same time, one of the votes might be lost (the concurrency of the code might get and set the vote at the same time, to the same number)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from Flask snippets:

```
@app.route('/set_cookie')
def cookie_insertion():
     redirect_to_index = redirect('/index')
     response = current_app.make_response(redirect_to_index )  
     response.set_cookie('cookie_name',value='values')
     return response
```

Link: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/30/